# Systemd service does not write python script to file, python script runs nominally when executed from cli

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, systemd

Working with a raspberry pi zero w, setup a script for monitoring a bme280 sensor with values written to a file. This works great when the script is started from the command line, when the script is started via systemd the file is not written. Please find below the script and systemd service.

Have set the Standard output to an absolute path with no luck, the python script write directive is set to absolute path as well.

Systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=bme280 sensor log startup
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/bme.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi
StandardOutput=file:/home/pi/senselog.csv
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=pi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

python script:

```py
import time
from time import strftime
import board
import busio
import adafruit_bme280

# Create library object using our Bus I2C port
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
bme280 = adafruit_bme280.Adafruit_BME280_I2C(i2c,address=0x76)

# OR create library object using our Bus SPI port
#spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, board.MOSI, board.MISO)
#bme_cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D10)
#bme280 = adafruit_bme280.Adafruit_BME280_SPI(spi, bme_cs)

# change this to match the location's pressure (hPa) at sea level
bme280.sea_level_pressure = 1013.25

with open("/home/pi/senselog.csv", "a") as log:
    while True:

        temp_h = bme280.temperature
        humidity = bme280.humidity
        pressure = bme280.pressure
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str([temp_h,humidity,pressure])))
        time.sleep(60)
```

If I delete the senselog.csv file, then on boot the systemd service creates the file fresh but with no data, any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Should it be `file:///home/pi/senselog.csv` instead of `file:/home/pi/senselog.csv`, anyway that is not the issue, i think

Comment: Could you check and see `journalctl -xe -f -u <your_service_name>` ?

Comment: @hansolo here is the output of journalctl: ``` journalctl -xe -f -u bme.service
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 10:16:44 PDT. --
Mar 26 10:08:39 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started bme280 sensor log startup.
-- Subject: Unit bme.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit bme.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Comment: Hey, now only i noticed, you have not defined the `Type` of the service. Considering your script,  could you try `Type=simple` in the `[Service]` section ?

Comment: Added Type=simple to the service with no change in behavior..

Comment: `systemctl daemon-reload` ?

Comment: So, from what you say, it is running the python script, and exiting at `with open("/home/pi/senselog.csv", "a") as log:` line. I am not sure, what's the problem. Sorry

Comment: @hansolo when I call the script from the cli via: ```python3 bme.py``` the script runs appropriately and logs sensor readings every x seconds to the senselog.csv file by appending the read value. when the service runs on boot to start the monitoring script, it shows the service being run successful but it does not write the data to senselog.csv. Why doesn't the script write to the file when it is started as a service?

Comment: Here is the output of the status command: ```$ systemctl status bme.service
● bme.service - bme280 sensor log startup
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bme.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-03-26 10:34:09 PDT; 6min ago
 Main PID: 350 (python3)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bme.service
           └─350 /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/bme.py >1 /home/pi/senselog.csv

Mar 26 10:34:09 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started bme280 sensor log startup.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution is to actually call .close() on the file we are writing to in the python script, then the systemd service works as expected. Shout out to this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/83549/python-script-wont-write-data-when-ran-from-cron very last answer = f.close()

and the working script file:

````
from time import strftime
import board
import busio
import adafruit_bme280

# Create library object using our Bus I2C port
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
bme280 = adafruit_bme280.Adafruit_BME280_I2C(i2c,address=0x76)

# OR create library object using our Bus SPI port
#spi = busio.SPI(board.SCK, board.MOSI, board.MISO)
#bme_cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D10)
#bme280 = adafruit_bme280.Adafruit_BME280_SPI(spi, bme_cs)

# change this to match the location's pressure (hPa) at sea level
bme280.sea_level_pressure = 1013.25

with open("/home/pi/senselog.csv", "w") as log:
    while True:

        temp_h = bme280.temperature
        humidity = bme280.humidity
        pressure = bme280.pressure
        log.write("{0},{1}\n".format(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),str([temp_h,humidity,pressure])))
        log.close()
        time.sleep(60) ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `file` attribute to `StandardOutput` only became available with `systemd` version 236. What version do you have?

```
pi@wifi-relay:~ $ systemd --version

systemd 232
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

If it's less than version 236 and you can't/don't want to upgrade, you could simply update your `ExecStart` line to:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/bme.py >1 /home/pi/senselog.csv
```

...then put back the `StandardOutput` line back to the default.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, the pi is on version 233 so I edited the service as you directed with no change in file writing behavior. Other thoughts?